# Converting data as string into DataFrame without losing columns name

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a data like this sample:

```
                                                         0 2017   IX 2018       X 2018       X 2018       X 2018        0 2017   IX 2018   X 2018    X 2018   X 2018
                                                                                             0 2017       IX 2018                                    0 2017   IX 2018
    UKUPNO                                               1.053    1.075         1.093        103,8        101,7         1.633    1.669     1.701      104,2    101,9
A   Poljoprivreda, šumarstvo i ribolov                     907      888           925        102,0        104,2         1.394    1.356     1.420      101,9    104,7
B   Vađenje ruda i kamena                                  913      919           839         91,9         91,3         1.395    1.406     1.297       93,0     92,2
C   Prerađivačka industrija                                769      764           775        100,8        101,4         1.176    1.169     1.187      100,9    101,5
D   Proizvodnja i snabdijevanje                          1.574    1.570         1.647        104,6        104,9         2.459    2.455     2.579      104,9    105,1
    električnom energijom, plinom,
    parom i klimatizacija
```

My code is:

```
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(t.strip()), delim_whitespace=True, header=None)
```

I read all possible solution(documentation and examples) but I didn't find answer.My question is,  which is the easiest way to create DataFrame, and especial include value:0 2017   IX 2018       X 2018 .....(which is my rows[0,1] as my  columns name.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add the code you ran to drop all NaNs?  You probably dropped all rows that had at least one NaN value.  Also, can you clarify how those first two rows need to become columns?  They will be column labels?  There are repeating values in those rows, so how do you want to handle those multiple 2018 values?  Can you add those column labels so we can see how the final dataframe should look?

Comment: Also, it's not clear right now how many columns in your dataframe are being taken up by your text.  I see sometimes there are three words on one line, sometimes there are four.  How many dataframe columns are those values?

Comment: I use this code for drop NaNs:df.dropna(how="any").Yes that kind of columns are repeating and I want them. I am going to create  9 columns, for the rest of dataframe i will put another data.Thank you

Comment: I use this code to:df[0] = df[0].ffill()
df[1] = df[0].map(df[1].groupby(df[0]).agg(lambda x: ' '.join(x)))
df = df.dropna(how='any')
df. But i lost first three rows, i don'T why.

Comment: i get complete dataframe when I use this code df = pd.read_fwf(pd.compat.StringIO(t),header=None,skiprows=1)

df[0] = df[0].ffill()
df[1] = df[0].map(df[1].groupby(df[0]).agg(lambda x: ' '.join(x)))
df = df.dropna(axis=0)
df but I lose first 2 rows.

Comment: You lose rows because both df.dropna(how='any') and df.dropna(axis=0) drop rows with at least one NA value.  how='any' and axis=0 are default parameter values for dropna().  There is too much going on in your problem to provide a good answer and it's not possible to reproduce your dataframe.  I recommend you split up the problem into compact questions (e.g., how to create column labels, how to merge rows, etc.) and post separate questions for each one.

Comment: ok thank you.I will.With read_table I get all my data I want but with tight table.I need to figure out how to spred it out.

Comment: Thank you very much.I solve my problem with your sugestions.